# Do all android versions Api-8 and above have back button

Tags: android

Is it correct that back button is available in all android phones/tablets API-8 and above ? Since if it is not a standard feature I would like to put ActionBarsherlock in my app for navigation

My app totally relies on the existence of a back button is it correct approach or should the action bar must be provided on certain versions ?

Thank you

Comment: Just advice about ActionBar: support-library contains implementation of ActionBar, so you don't need to use external libs like ActionBarSherlok

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about that, very useful,I would avoid using thirdparty stuff thanks.

Comment: @Foxinsocks Just tried to use the support library v7 unfortunately it can not provide ActionBar for PreferenceActivity .. sad. may have to end up using ActionBarSherlock :/

Answer (score 1):

yes it is available on all API-8 + android phones, to keep consistancy though, the home icon in the action bar should be used as a back button as well :

from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Home

> Note: Up navigation is distinct from the back navigation provided by the system Back button. The Back button is used to navigate in reverse chronological order through the history of screens the user has recently worked with. It is generally based on the temporal relationships between screens, rather than the app's hierarchy structure (which is the basis for up navigation).

Comment: Thanks, my app currently does not have any action bar in any activity. I expect a back button in all models, is this correct expectation ?